# Dropwizard no longer supports Java 6

Tags: java, rest, maven, dropwizard

I want to use version 0.6.2 of drop wizard, but it seems to not exist on a maven repository anymore.

The original Maven include was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

but according to the website (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yammer.dropwizard/dropwizard-core/0.6.2), the group and artifact names have changed. On the new page (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-core), the version 0.6.2 does not exist. When I try to do a include like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

it doesn’t work. Is there any fix for this? **I need to use Dropwizard that supports Java 6.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This still works, don't switch over to `io.dropwizard` unless you want to switch to 0.7.x. 0.6.2 is not available with groupId io.dropwizard. The message is just telling you that future releases will be in the new groupId.